# How to distinguish between private key and public which are visible in text editors?

Tags: public-key

I would like to know how to understand which one is private key and public key while seeing them in raw text format?

Comment: _Usually_ this is either defined by context (some random stranger usually doesn't give you a _private_ key) or because there's a header / specifier in the file clarifying what kind of key it is. Also encryption is usually a hint towards a private key being stored.

Answer (score 0):

The Certificates are made based on specific standards. Mostly, the Public and Private keys will be having **Header** and **Footer** based on the encryption standard. You can differentiate between the keys by viewing the **Header** and/or the **file format**.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I know private and the public keys have headers as well. But I have the keys as plain text. So I can't distinguish it :(